# I feel heavy when I run and is lacking lower body strength need help

Tags: long-distance-running, bodyweight, stamina, lower-body-strength

Every time I run in P.E. (Physical Education) it seems I'm last of many. When it comes to speed I struggle but for long distance runs I'm able to last longer than most people. Specifically: the impact on my feet feels heavy.

I do the right posture too, plus I only weigh 52 kg (New Zealand measurements) so I'm not really heavy at all but I feel like my lower body is weighing me down when I try to run. More than anything I can't run for far too long as I'm low on stamina and power in strength. The only thing that helps me in competitions involving running or jumping is my determination and integrity.

Comment: I don't run, so I'll let someone else step in here. but I would check out this question for some form tips: https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/11702/proper-running-form-landing-on-balls-of-feet

Comment: First, this is great. There aren't many people at a school age that realize that if something isn't as you want it to be, put in the work and fix it. But could you add more details? How old are you? How large are you? What exercises do you do regularly besides pe? How much time do you want to put in? Is joining an institution consistent with your goals (e.g. an athletics team or a gym and so on) an option? Do you want to be specifically a good jumper and sprinter or are you interested in becoming more athletic in general?

Comment: 4.7 inches. 15 y/r. and right now i'm trying to rebuild and stamina. i do badminton as a hobby i also do some biking and i'm starting to do basic exercises. i did undergo a intense training program that lasted 8 weeks with firefighters, police officers, and medics for support but i sustained a injury at week 2 in my hips because my lack of exercise but i was stubborn so i pushed myself every day till i could no longer go on. which resulted me having to quit but i'm trying again and again till i graduate.

Comment: @Ripeka.E It would be great if you could add those details to the question itself. Also, one more question. What is "short" and "long"? 100m and 1km, or 1km and 10km?

Answer (score 3):

When starting out, we so commonly jump straight into running. This is natural, perhaps, since we all remember running around so effortlessly when we were young children. But it is so easy to forget that we also skipped, jumped, climbed trees, and suspended and swung ourselves on the monkey bars, too. Few of us can do these things without risk as we get older, unless we have built up to them. The reason is simple: if we do not maintain vigorous or strenuous physical activity continuously throughout our lives, our size outgrows our physical capacity.

So even though you may not be physically heavy relative to the average, you may still be heavy in relation to your current physical strength. That is, you may have poor *relative* muscle, tendon, and ligament (joint) strength. *And this is normal.*

Contrary to the way we commonly think of it, running is *very* physically demanding. [Peak ground reaction forces are typically 2–3 times body weight, while peak forces on the tibia (lower leg) are typically 6–14 times body weight](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6336327/)! It is natural that you would feel ‘heavy’ when you run, if you have not been running consistently for a significant period of time.

*So what can you do about it?*

The obvious answer is to build your running volume up slowly until such time that it begins to feel more comfortable and manageable. But I would like to suggest something that is rarely considered.

In contrast to how we commonly view it, running is a moderately-advanced exercise. As such, it is often better to begin with a foundation exercise—in this case, *walking*. Walking conditions all of the same muscles and structures, but without the impact (peak loads) that running applies. *And good walkers make good runners.*

The pace you should strive for depends on your height and leg length; however, it should be punchy, but comfortable and sustainable. You should take long strides and keep the legs turning over rapidly. Your target speed should be between ~6.5 km/h (9.23 min/km) if you are ~150 centimetres (5') and ~8 km/h (7.5 min/km) if you are ~183 centimetres (6') tall. Different terrain (including uneven ground) and hills should be included between regular bouts in order to develop additional strength in the muscles and joints.

Only once you can comfortably maintain your target pace for five kilometres or more, should you begin to alternate bouts of walking with running. Start with shorter distances, and lengthen them gradually as you feel the body is able to keep up. Skipping (jump-rope) can be useful as a supplement to further develop joint strength—particularly in the ankles.

*Needless to say, there are any number of ‘correct’ ways that you might approach this problem, but I hope this suggestion provides you with another perspective.*

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Humans are like horses, we have different means of fast movement.

They have:  trots, lopes and gallops

We have: jogs,skips, running and sprints.
Our bodies eventually get used to the stress and improve with time, but some gaits are prefered over others.

Skipping can be preferable for people how are worried about the impact of their movements - [source](https://enell.com/blogs/blog/it-s-time-to-skip-your-workout-skipping-is-better-than-walking-and-running)

It is also a better option when it comes to burning calories - [source](https://www.healthline.com/health-news/why-you-should-skip-for-exercise-instead-of-run#:~:text=The%20average%20peak%20force%20on,than%20runners%2C%20the%20study%20found.)